# my index page is empty i'm getting white page

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

i'm learning Django i did everything but when i'm getting empty white page. and with source code i'm getting only tags.  i put my views.py and index.html i'm not getting even error in terminal i'm using virtualenv. and when i try to enter website i'm not getting error 
September 24, 2019 - 18:09:51
Django version 2.2.5, using settings 'Web.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% for title in titles %}
   <title>{{ titles.title }}</title>
{% endfor %}

</head>
<body>

    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p> By {{ post.author}} on {{ post.date_posted }}</p>
        <p> {{ post.concent}} </p>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

titles = [

{'title':'My Own CMS'}
],

posts =[

{   
    'author': 'CoreyMS',
    'title':'Blog Post 1',
    'content': 'First Post',
    'date_posted': 'August 26,2019'       
},
{
    'author': 'George',
    'title':'Blog Post 2',
    'content': 'seccond Post',
    'date_posted': 'August 29,2019'       
},

]

def home(request):
headset = {

    'title': titles
    },

context = {
    'posts': posts
}
return render(request, 'blog/index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request,'blog/shesaxeb.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the context dictionary, but didn't add it to the return.

```
context = {
    'posts': posts,
}


def about(request):
    return render(request,'blog/shesaxeb.html', context)
```